# how to convert sampler2D when moving from glsl to metal?

Tags: opengl, glsl, metal

I am trying to convert a glsl shader to metal, and even though there are lot's of cheat sheets and tutorials on the internet, I can't get my head around what to do with `sampler2D` and `texture` calls. [This](https://dench.flatlib.jp/opengl/glsl_hlsl) cheat sheet had a lot of stuff covered, but in the section about samplers, it does not show to define the sampler itself (in terms of the type). My next attempt was to take MoltenVK and try to convert a small glsl shader with a sampler to metal, to see how it handles that.

So here is my minimal glsl shader:

```
#version 300 es 
in vec4 TexCoord;
out vec4 fragColor;
uniform sampler2D plane[4];

void main()
{
    fragColor = texture(plane[0], TexCoord.xy);
}
```

here is the output of `MoltenGLShaderConverter` from MoltenVK:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wparentheses-equality"
using namespace metal;
struct xlatMtlShaderInput {
  float4 TexCoord;
};
struct xlatMtlShaderOutput {
  float4 fragColor [[color(0)]];
};
struct xlatMtlShaderUniform {
  texture2d<float> plane[4];
};
fragment xlatMtlShaderOutput test_frag (xlatMtlShaderInput _mtl_i [[stage_in]], constant xlatMtlShaderUniform& _mtl_u [[buffer(0)]])
{
  xlatMtlShaderOutput _mtl_o;
  float4 tmpvar_1 = 0;
  tmpvar_1 = _mtl_u.plane[0].sample(_mtlsmp__mtl_u.plane[0], float2((_mtl_i.TexCoord.xy).x, (1.0 - (_mtl_i.TexCoord.xy).y)));
  _mtl_o.fragColor = tmpvar_1;
  return _mtl_o;
}
```

The nice thing here is that I actually learned that the Y axis is inverted, however this sample uses `_mtlsmp__mtl_u` without defining it. So I still do not know how to define the sampler.

Can anyone explain what am I missing? I see how I made a hack (but does it really affect anything) by taking a glsl shader, and setting the version to OpenGL ES 3.0, but does that affect anything?

Comment: Apple's documentation is a beautiful place to start with. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/creating_and_sampling_textures

Comment: @codetiger I read this, but what confused me was that the glsl shader does not provide the semantics (or I am too inexperienced with glsl that I do not know how to deduce it) that the metal sampler takes in it's ctor. And on top of that the MoltenVK output confused me even more.

Comment: The first parameter in `sample` function is a texture sampler. This is very similar to what we call filters in OpenGL `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);`

Comment: @codetiger oh thanks a lot, this was the missing link :) So the missing piece for me was that in glsl these things are defined with OpenGL calls, not in the shader itself (at least in this scenario). And now I actually found where the code base that I am working with does that. Many thanks, if you post this as an answer I'll gladly accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Metal, some configurations like texture filter and others are defined in the shader unlike OpenGL which uses GL methods to define it in the application.

To answer your exact question on the first parameter in `sample` function.This is similar to Texture filter function in OpenGL

`glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);`